# How to by-pass server login when using custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

I am working with MVC2 and I have created a custom AuthorizeAtrribute callled FilterIPAttribute and this is how i override the AuthorizeCore:

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        string userIpAddress = httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;

        try {
            return CheckAllowedIPs(userIpAddress);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the exception, probably something wrong with the configuration
        }

        return false; // if there was an exception, then we return false - denying access
    }
```

It works fine when I run it locally, however when I uploaded my code to a webserver; On trying to access a page where the controller is decorated with this FilterIP attribute, i get a popup asking me to login to the server.

Any one else encountered a similar issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the only method that you've overriden?

Comment: Well I have also overriden the OnAuthorization method:         public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }